# ImageView Scaling for iPhone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, autolayout, image-scaling, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

So Im making a game without the use of auto-layout.  I have used constraints to scale everything and it worked perfectly. However, there are 12 image views that scroll down. 6 on the right a 6 on the left.

This is done based on a code i've written and places the images via arc4random.

The images on the left are completely fine and scroll down so that there is no gap between the side of the screen and the image. As do the images on the right when using the iphone 4s and 5.

HOWEVER.. when it comes to trying this on the iphone 6 and 6+, alot of the times, there is a gap between the image and the side of the screen on the RIGHT. the LEFT is fine.  I want to know how I could solve this issue. This is more of a general problem so dont need to include code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus support for the app so that they work fine on the new devices (via scaling)
Remove "Launch Screen File" from Target General Settings and if you are using Asset Catalogs for Launch images, under right panel for the asset catalog under Launch Images-> remove launch images for iPhone Portrait and Landscape for the category 'iOS 8.0 and later'
This is a workaround that makes iPhone6 and iPhone6Plus to scale views according to the screen size.